# How to limit user input to one string per attempt - Python

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, limit, maxlength

complete beginner, been learning the past several weeks and now working on creating a game as part of my University course.

I decided to get complex (for a beginner), as I was picking it up quite well, but this one has me stumped.

I want to limit the user to only one string per attempt. Currently they can enter as many characters as they like (asdfghjkl) and it will enter each correct character in to the game, meaning they can win in 3 attempts or less. What I am aiming for is if they enter more than one character, it returns a custom error message, and then prompts them to try again. Included the full game as I wasn't entirely sure which parts to include based on responses..

```
    '''
    import random
    import time


    file = open("name_game.txt", "r+")
    f = file.readlines()
    word = random.choice(f)


    def age():
        try:
            user_age = int(input("First, How old are you? "))
            if user_age > 11:  # 11 due to high school age.
                print("You're a bit old for this!")
                print("\nY = Yes, N = No")
                user_input = input("Would you like to continue anyway? ")
                if user_input == "Y" or user_input == "y":
                    user_name()
                elif user_input == "N" or user_input == "n":
                    print("Exiting Game")
                    time.sleep(1.0)
                    exit()
                else:
                    print("You entered an invalid option.\nExiting.")
            elif user_age <= 3:
                print("You're too young for this, sorry!")
                print("Exiting Game")
                time.sleep(1.0)  # exiting game as they can't continue.
                exit()
            else:
                print("Continue!")
                user_name()
        except ValueError:
            print("*"*31)
            print("Please enter a numerical value.")
            print("*" * 31)
            time.sleep(1)
            age()


    def user_name():
        name_input = input("What is your name? ")
        print("Guess the word,", name_input + "!")
        print("Number of letters in word:", len(word.strip()))


    def try_again():
        char = ''
        attempts = 10
        score = 0

        while attempts > 0:
            fail_count = 0

            for letter in word.strip():
                if letter in char:
                    print(letter, end=" ")
                else:
                    print("_ ", end="")
                    fail_count += 1

            print("\nScore:", score)

            if fail_count == 0:
                print("Congrats, you're a winner!! \nResult:", word.title())
                print("Your final Score: ", score)  # print the score
                user_input = input("Would you like to play again? ")
                if user_input == "Y" or user_input == "y":
                    try_again()
                    break
                elif user_input == "N" or user_input == "n":
                    print("Exiting Game")
                    time.sleep(1.0)
                    exit()

            guess_letter = input("Guess a letter:")
            char += guess_letter

            if guess_letter not in word:
                attempts -= 1
                score -= 1
                print("Incorrect \nYou have", + attempts, "attempts left")

                if attempts == 0:
                    print("The word was:", word.title())
                    print("Better luck next time!")
                    user_input = input("Would you like to play again? ")
                    if user_input == "Y" or user_input == "y":
                        try_again()
                        break
                    elif user_input == "N" or user_input == "n":
                        print("Exiting Game")
                        time.sleep(1.0)
                        exit()
                        break


    age()
    try_again()
    '''
```

I am also having trouble with the score, where it seems to be adding the number of correct characters in the index together. So if they guess a + b + c then it returns +3 to the score. I cannot seem to figure out how to only increment the score by 1.

Any help would be much appreciated? I have been searching for days.

Answer (score 0):

```
while len(userinputvariablehere) != 1:
    print("String is too long.")
    userinputvariable = input("Input thing again: ")
```

This is what I think you are asking for, it will just ask the user to input the string until it is 1 character in length. Again this question does not really make much sense to me so this is the best I can offer, sorry. When you say too many strings the only way I can make sense of this is assuming you mean characters, if they can constantly input more strings then you have a logic error somewhere calling the input function over and over I assume.

Comment: I have tried something similar to this, but I was unsure where to put this. My code was something along the lines of.. 

while len(char) > 1: 
    print("Too many characters")

But again, wasn't too sure where to enter it.

I have also changed "string" to "character", as that is exactly what I meant :)

Comment: This would be done as a check straight after input, it will ask the user for inputs until it is 1 character in length.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to have it check the length of the inputted string, and if it's greater than 1, continue to the next iteration while not affecting score or fail attempts. Here is how you might go about it:

```py
while attempts > 0:
    if len(inputted_character) > 1:
        # I don't know the name of your input, name it however is necessary.
        print("please only input a single character.")
        continue  # this will jump to the next iteration without running the rest of the code in the loop.

    # continue with your code below.
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I had previously, I was just missing the "continue" statement. It still gives me the same issue I was encountering though, where when you enter more than one, it repeats "please only input a single character.", until I stop the code. It also does this if you guess more than one correct character in the word too. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, my code doesn't actually ask for the input, so it doesn't get any new input in each iteration. You'll have to make sure you ask for input inside the loop but before the length check. Is it before?

Comment: I have updated it so it includes the entire game, There are still things I am figuring out. But the score increment and only allowing one character to be entered at a time are the two baffling me the most. I know that the score is inside a loop, which is why it is adding the index together, rather than just adding 1 at a time, but I cannot figure out where to put the code to stop that happening. Apologies for the lengthy code.